# Why is this matrix code not behaving?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm running this code:

```
rows_columns <- matrix(nrow = 675, ncol = 24)

extra_cols <- matrix(c(rep(NA, nrow(rows_columns)*(ncol(rows_columns))), 
nrow = nrow(rows_columns), ncol = ncol(rows_columns)))
```

I expect it to yield a matrix with `nrow = 675`, and `ncol = 24`. However, instead it's `str` is:

```
int [1:16202, 1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

How come?

Comment: Misplaced parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be

```
rows_columns <- matrix(nrow = 675, ncol = 24)

extra_cols <- matrix(c(rep(NA, nrow(rows_columns)*(ncol(rows_columns)))), 
nrow = nrow(rows_columns), ncol = ncol(rows_columns))
```

you write the command

```
nrow = nrow(rows_columns), ncol = ncol(rows_columns)
```

inside the c function